# F# Evaluate variables passed into functions as arguments (out of scope)

Tags: variables, scope, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation, f#-3.0

I'm working on a function that takes two arguments: a match value and a list of tuples.  The goal is to match the first value (a string) in each tuple against the match value (also a string) and add the second value (an int) in those matching tuples to a new list, which is returned in sorted order.  I started out with:

```
let getElems strMatch tupList =
let rec loop acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | hd :: tl ->
        match hd with
        | (strMatch, v) -> loop (v :: acc) tl
        | _ -> loop (acc) tl
List.sort (loop [] tupList)
```

...but came to realize that strMatch is out of scope as a pattern match so the second rule would never get matched.  So I started trying to pass strMatch to the inner code blocks like so:

```
let getElems strMatch tupList =
let rec loop strMatch acc tupList =
    match tupList with
    | [] -> acc
    | hd :: tl ->
        match hd with
        | (strMatch, v) -> loop strMatch (v :: acc) tl
        | _ -> loop strMatch (acc) tl
List.sort (loop strMatch [] tupList)
```

...but the value is still out of scope in the match blocks.  I suppose it would be possible to pass strMatch into those blocks but this seems messy and I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way.

EDIT: So here are my results...
First, I get the warning "This rule will never be matched."  When I run the function as-is:

```
getElems "A" [("A",5);("BB",6);("AA",9);("A",0)];;
> val it : int list = [0; 5; 6; 9]
```

But if I hard code strMatch as "A" in the function:

```
getElems "A" [("A",5);("BB",6);("AA",9);("A",0)];;
> val it : int list = [0; 5]
```

Which is what is desired.  But I'm required to take any match as an argument.

Comment: Why do you think it's out of scope?

Comment: Because I get a warning that "This rule will never be matched", when I run the function all values return true, and when I replace strMatch with a hard coded value it runs as expected.  It seems to me that the program views strMatch in that code block as a new value as it does with v so that anything matches.  I'll add my results above...

Comment: That's correct: A variable in a pattern matches any value, like `v` does. But that has nothing to do with scoping.

Comment: I haven't used F# but try something like `| (str, v) when str = strMatch -> ...`.

Comment: Well that does it- thank you so much!